# Calculating CCA of a starter battery

Tags: batteries, amperage, power-engineering

I'm searching for some kinda of formula that can be used to calculate the Cold Cranking Amps (which seems to be an industry term for a 30 sec discharge pulse current at a specific temperature, 0 degrees F) of a battery. I work in design, what I'm trying to do figure out the required CCA to start an engine and compare it to the CCA of the battery installed. The idea being to make sure the batteries speced aren't oversized.

I came across the equation:

E = V* I* t = V* A-hr

Which makes sense to me intuitively, but doesn't account for the effect of low temperature battery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The CCA is a number in the spec. sheet of a particular battery so designers/users will have confidence that their engine can be started at that temperature , its not a formula. The equation you state is for battery capacity which again is **only a general indication** of how long the charge in the battery **may** last at a certain current drain (definitely not linear).

Comment: @JImDearden Maybe I'm just being difficult, and I'll hopefully be able to track down the spec sheets, but I really find it baffling that there is no formula that describes the amp output of a battery. I guess that happens when you start mess around outside your area of expertise. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: There are general relationships (the higher the capacity, the greater the current it can supply or the longer it lasts) but each battery manufacturer will have their own wrinkles which may come down to the specific electrolyte mixture used, electrode treatments, plate geometry /structure.  Some are much better than others even if they are rated at the same nominal capacity. Rather than a formula you should use graphical analysis to show how different  batteries will react under different range conditions of current, temperature, age etc. so that their performance can be compared.

Comment: I recall CCA is the current sustained at T+30sec at 0'C (32F) into a 7.5V shunt and CA is generally 25% higher at room temp but degrades each year of normal life use. So margin and life testing is essential to validate assumptions.  Ah is more a measure of the electrolyte and ESR a measure of the conductor plates both which affect CCA.

Answer (score 1):

No such formula exists.

The problem is that the current you can get from a battery is based on the exact temperature and details of the battery. Even if temperature is specified, the details of the battery construction vary. Different batteries that have the same voltage and same amp-hour capacity may have different cold cranking amp values.

Consider for example this: you may have 12V 45Ah deep cycle battery and 12V 45Ah starter battery. Which one of these would you expect to have higher CCA value? You probably guessed it correctly: the 12V 45Ah starter battery has a higher CCA value.

So, if the only thing you know is that the battery is 12V and 45Ah, you can't deduce the CCA.

You really need the datasheet of the battery!

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, you certainly seem to know more than I do about this, but I can't fathom that there is no formula to figure out the CCA. It's fine if I don't have enough information, I can say that, but I can't go to my supervisor and say "no one knows"

Comment: You can test the battery and estimate the CCA.

Answer (score 1):

The CCA of a battery is merely a rating that manufacturers give it.  If you want a formula to calculate the theoretical, temperature dependent CCA of an individual battery it would require extensive differential equations and a very in-depth knowledge of the battery's chemistry, and it would be even more difficult to accurately predict the actual performance of a specific battery, as there are a massive amount of variables that can affect CCA.

So no, there is no formula to calculate CCA.  It is simply a rating.

Comment: Correct no formula.  It is a test procedure with very specific metrics. Multiple standards organizations set the metrics.  SAE sets the procedure.

Comment: Yeah. For education: We have one battery that we did quite a bit of CCA testing on, we have ratings outside the typical standards for testing as we have a certain customer that likes things "rugged". We have ratings for temperatures as low -40C.

Answer (score 1):

CCA cannot be “measured,” but it can be “estimated” and the process can take a week per battery. A full CCA test is tedious and is seldom done. To test CCA, apply different discharge currents to see which amperage keeps the battery above a set voltage while cold.

**SAE Test**

Fully charge battery according
to SAE J537 and cool to -18°C (0°F) for 24 hours. While at subfreezing temperature, apply a discharge current equal to the specified CCA. (500 CCA battery discharges at 500A.)

**To pass, the voltage must stay above 7.2V (1.2V/cell) for 30 seconds.**

---

**IEC Test**

Fully charge battery according
to SAE J537 and cool to -18°C (0°F) for 24 hours. While at subfreezing temperature, apply a discharge current equal to the specified CCA. (500 CCA battery discharges at 500A.)

**To pass, the voltage must stay above 8.4V for 60 seconds.**

---

**DIN Test**

Fully charge battery according
to SAE J537 and cool to -18°C (0°F) for 24 hours. While at subfreezing temperature, apply a discharge current equal to the specified CCA. (500 CCA battery discharges at 500A.)

**To pass, the voltage must stay above 9V for 30s and 6V for 150s**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

A starter battery specs list both 20-hour discharge capacity (in Ah) AND CCA in Ampere, which is also a capacity, but for some pretty high current discharge where lead-acid batteries are profoundly non-linear.

The capacity in both modes usually differs 10..30-fold.

Both of them can only be tested and not really measured (except by testing multiple times and approaching the right value).

Both of them are usually guaranteed only for a new battery and should be derated for aging AND for using a partially-charged battery.

They are related to different modes of operation and a battery used in some car (or other battery-started engine) is selected to fulfil both.

A battery of a given size is a compromise between 20-hour capacity, CCA, cycle life, calendar life, price and other objectives. Each one of these can be tweaked against others - more active mass gives more 20-hour capacity but leaves less room for conducting paths so less CCA and so on.

... and, a sane car w/ 2.5l gasoline engine in a moderate weather can be started w/ a new, fully charged 9Ah UPS battery. I had to try once and it worked.

It doesn't mean that the original 60Ah/600CCA battery is over-engineered. I had to start it in this exotic manner exactly because the original battery was too smal for my (rather exotic, but pretty much legitimate) use case.

Answer (score 0):

No way to calculate it properly afaik.

However, some of the cheaper Chinese battery testers on the market (Biltema, Topdon etc) simply seem to estimate it by measuring the battery's internal resistance (R), then present the CCA as:

- **CCA = 2985,6204 / R**
  (with R in mOhm), CCA rounded to nearest multiple of 5.

Very strange. I have tried to find out why they do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the equation CCA = 3051.85 / R where R is in μΩ.

For example:-

- R= 10.28 μΩ.
- CCA = 3051.85/10.28
  = 296 CCA

Check other samples given. I found this real data in YouTube.

Thanks!

[image]